# What's going on in this panorama in remote British Columbia?

Tags: british-columbia

Sometimes when I'm bored I'll browse places I might like to visit on Google Maps and/or Google Street View.  During one such session, I came across this user-submitted panorama in the mountains of British Columbia, close to Graham-Laurier Provincial Park.

https://www.google.com/maps/@56.448904,-123.7311853,3a,64.1y,348.75h,85.38t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sAF1QipMWfFrjVwl2dPzsDNg0oz51ybSkvlBQG8VJqSk_!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipMWfFrjVwl2dPzsDNg0oz51ybSkvlBQG8VJqSk_%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya141.00002-ro0-fo100!7i8704!8i4352

I see a small helicopter (that presumably transported the photographer to the spot), several wooden platforms perched on the mountainsides, what might be a cargo container, and no people.

What's going on here?

Is this the early stage of building remote cabins?  A research facility?  Mining or other industry?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel as defined in the [help]

Comment: I'd bet it's some sort of seismic monitoring installation.